# Ember App Kit: Calling a view gives me Assertion Failed error

Tags: ember.js, highcharts, coffeescript, ember-app-kit

I have a View:

```
HighChart = Ember.View.extend
  //code...

`export default HighChart`
```

*(this is coffeescript syntax)*

The file name is: `high-chart.coffee`

The file is stored in the root `views` directory

I want to call the view from within this template: `templates/accounts/index.hbs`

Here is the handlebars I am using: `{{ view HighChart }}`

I get: `Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Unable to find view at path 'HighChart'`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put it in quotes

```
{{ view 'HighChart' }}
```